# how to check a object who create and hold it when no gcroot in windbg

Tags: .net, windbg

i get a LOH object,and want to know who create and hold it.

```
!do 28d2a0a0
```

[image]

[image]

**28d2a0a0** object no hold any object and not by other object hold.which function method to created it?thanks.

[image]

Comment: Windbg won't provide which function created it. Usually byte[] are used for I/O by the framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `!sosex.refs` to find out what references the object, but the debugger can't tell you what created it.  You'll have to rely on code review for that once you've built up a ref chain.